# oracle apex email templates: generating html

Tags: oracle-apex, email-templates

say we have created an email template `NOTAWOL`

If I am to report all students in the class in an HTML table, I'll need  tags for each person in the class.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>jane doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>john doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the problem is that number of rows would that table has was unknown while email template being created.

I've tried creating a template where I placed my anchors and some opening tags. to make it a bit more dynamic, I tried adding a substitution string at the end, before closing tags

something like:

```
<table>
 <th>student list</th>
 #LOOPS#
</table>
```

the idea was to create a

```
l_loops CLOB;
```

and collect all student records by concatanating them with proper `<td> </td>` tags.

however, when I replace `#LOOPS#` with `l_loops` I see raw html content in the page.

question: email templates are not meant to be used in such cases? or is there a wise approach to create tables based on number of rows?

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A substitution variable is a string. There is no looping mechanism available (yet ?). Solution is to not use email templates or to build a solution on top of the existing functionality. A nice solution is described here: https://srihariravva.blogspot.com/2020/05/email-templates-tabular-data.html

Comment: thank you very much. I got the trick from this blog. In my case, I decided to use #LOOPS!RAW# but your answer is the answer anyway.

Comment: Happy to hear it works